# converting a matrix to string

Tags: java, matrix, tostring

I am working on writing a matrix, but unfortunately I am stuck with the output.
Instead of showing a matrix, it shows me something like:

actual matrix is 
Matrix@512fb063

I need to convert the matrix to a string so that the output will look like this:

```
expected the matrix: 
3   8   72
4   6   60
253 2   1
```

the code that I've written is this:

```
import java.util.Random;
final public class Matrix {
private final int size1;             // number of rows
private final int size2;             // number of columns
private final int[][] data;   // M-by-N array

// create size1-by-size2 matrix of 0's
public Matrix(int size1, int size2) {
    this.size1 = size1;
    this.size2 = size2;
    data = new int[size1][size2];
}

// create matrix based on 2d array
public Matrix(int[][] data) {
    size1 = data.length;
    size2 = data[0].length;
    this.data = new int[size1][size2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
                this.data[i][j] = data[i][j];
}

// creates and returns a random size1-by-size1 matrix with values between 0 and 255
public String toString(int size1, int size2) {
    Matrix A = new Matrix(size1, size2);
    String str = " ";
   final int white = 0;
   final int black = 255;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
        {

         A.data[i][j] = white + (int)(Math.random() * ((black ) ));
         str = (A.data[i][j]+"\t"+A.data[i][j+1]);
         if (i==size1 &&j==size2) str = (A.data[i][j]+"\n");

        }

     return str;  

 }
```

Comment: *"It's very urgent!"*  Too localized.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `public  String toString()` function. What you are doing now is creating a new function called `String toString(int size1, int size2)`.

Your new function is not called when writing:

```
 System.out.println(myMatrix);
```

You could either do:

```
 System.out.println(myMatrix.toString(2, 2));
```

or override the default `toString()` function.

So the following code should work:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Matrix A = new Matrix(size1, size2);
    String str = " ";
   final int white = 0;
   final int black = 255;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
        {

         A.data[i][j] = white + (int)(Math.random() * ((black ) ));
         str = (A.data[i][j]+"\t"+A.data[i][j+1]);
         if (i==size1 &&j==size2) str = (A.data[i][j]+"\n");

        }

     return str;  

 }
```

where `size1` and `size2` are variables in the class.

Comment: *"You need to override.."*  ..and when doing so, use `@Override` notation to avoid problems like this.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Isn't the whole code is the toString()  function?

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Does this help?

Comment: Not really, I am having a difficulty to understand where the problem exactly is. if str is written fine, and I return it, why doesn't eclipse show me the numbers of the matrix, but instead something else?

Comment: I only need to know how to covert an array into a string, and then I can do it

Comment: Because Java uses the `toString()` function to print contents and not your custom function. If you don't override `toString()`, Java will use a default print function, which just outputs the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return toString(size1,size2);
}
```

Edit : If you want to reflect the real content of your current Matrix :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < size1;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size2;j++)
        {
             sbResult.append(A.data[i][j]);
             sbResult.append("\t");
             sbResult.append(A.data[i][j+1]);

             if(i == size1 && j == size2)
             {
                 sbResult.append("\n");
             }
        }
    }

    return sbResult.toString();
}
```

Comment: the output should be: 3 8 72 4 6 60 253 2 1, but instead I got only:   253 1.. can someone explain why?

Comment: Probably because you toString() is not reflecting your Matrix content, I'll write you a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Your output of `actual matrix is Matrix@512fb063` is actually the memory address in Java that your instance of the class Matrix sits in. That's because your program doesn't know how to "print" this class - it doesn't magically know that you want a row/column representation of it.

You've got a number of options:

1. Your `toString(int size1, int size2)` is perfect. So when you want to print your matrix, you can go `System.out.println(someMatrix.toString(2,2))` will work where `someMatrix` is an instance of your Matrix class.
2. If you want it to work properly by you just going `System.out.println(someMatrix)` then you will need to overwrite your Matrix class' toString() function. You -almost- did that in your `toString(int size1, int size2)` function but it didn't work because it needs to match exactly the parameters, ie: `toString()` should take 0 parameters. You will need to write a `toString()` method which can then call your `toString(int size1, int size2)`

Comment: I have another problem now.. in the main class the matrix gets specific numbers, not random as I thought.. plus my output is a random number , instead of a whole matrix. How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you constructing your Matrix in your main class, and how do they want you to construct the specific matrix? Your output should be the whole matrix is simple - write a toString() method that goes through the 2D array and print out the elements, ie: go through each row, print out the element, and then when you hit that row, print a newline and the next rows start printing. Hint: You will need a for-for loop.

Comment: Hey guys! I changed my code a little, and now I am having some output of the matrix, but not all of it, why? my code of toString() is this:  public String toString() {
Matrix A = new Matrix( size1, size2);
String str = " ";
final int white = 0;
final int black = 255;
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
{

 
str = (data[i][0]+"\t"+data[i][j++]);
if (i==size1 &&j==size2) str = (data[i][j]+"\n");

}

return str;

}

Comment: What type of data do you want it to print, and what are you getting? There's actually a couple of things you can improve and I'll point them to you after. What's the point of the white/black idea?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you get the hashcode. Maybe you can use http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/ matrix implementation. 
I think this line is not working 
str = (A.data[i][j]+"\t"+A.data[i][j+1]);
Don't you get an IndexOutOfBoundexception? Anyway A.data[i][j+1] is always empty within the loop. By the way, Variables in Java are always lower case.