# Simple Java-solution for formatting string output for matrix

Tags: java, string, matrix, formatting, output

I have tried to find a simple Java-solution for formatting string output for matrix. The matrix can contain Numbers or Strings. It can be define as

```
Integer[][] myMatrix = new Integer[][]{
        new Integer[] {1,   2,  123456, 123},
        new Integer[] {12,  1234,   12,     1},
        new Integer[] {1,   123,    123456789,  12}
```

The formatter can be called as

```
String result = new Matrix2StringFormatter<>(myMatrix).toString();
```

I expect the readable output with correctly column width and right or left align as:

```
[1,   2,    123456,     123]
[12,  1234, 12,         1  ]
[1,   123,  123456789,  12 ]
```

Nice to have is the extension of class capabilities with setting of headers, footers, margin etc.
Relevant, but not sufficient solutions are:

1. [Stackoverflow: matrix-to-string-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497676/matrix-to-string-output)
2. [Stackoverflow: converting-a-matrix-to-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260739/converting-a-matrix-to-string)
3. [Class MatrixToString (use as parameter Matrix-class)](http://wordhoard.northwestern.edu/userman/javadoc/edu/northwestern/at/utils/math/matrix/MatrixToString.html)

Are there some better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately on my request no answer was given. That's why I developed a Java 8 class myself. This class exactly meets the requirements listed above. 
The call of formatter with setting of formatting options can be made as:

```
String result = new MatrixFormatter<>(doubleMatrix).setHeader("Table header").setHeaderSeparator('-').setFooterSeparator('=').setSolumnSeparator("|").setAllignCell(AllignCell.CENTER).toString();
```

You can find this class in GitHub:[matrixformatter](https://github.com/vsirotin/matrixformatter)